# DHT11 sensors keep printing 255 temperature and humidity when connect to ESP8266

Tags: c, arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to put my DHT11 data on AdafruitIO by my ESP8266 but it doesn't work and it keep printing out like this:

```
Read failFailed to read from DHT
Humidity: 255.00 %  Temperature: 255.00 *C
Humidity: 255.00 %  Temperature: 255.00 *C
Humidity: 255.00 %  Temperature: 255.00 *C
Read failFailed to read from DHT
Humidity: 255.00 %  Temperature: 255.00 *C
Humidity: 255.00 %  Temperature: 255.00 *C
Humidity: 255.00 %  Temperature: 255.00 *C
Read failFailed to read from DHT
Humidity: 255.00 %  Temperature: 255.00 *C
Humidity: 255.00 %  Temperature: 255.00 *C
Humidity: 255.00 %  Temperature: 255.00 *C
```

Here is my code

```
#include "DHT.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

#define DHTPIN 5   

#define DHTTYPE DHT11   


DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  Serial.println("DHTxx test!");

  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  if (isnan(t) || isnan(h)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT");
  } else {
    Serial.print("Humidity: "); 
    Serial.print(h);
    Serial.print(" %\t");
    Serial.print("Temperature: "); 
    Serial.print(t);
    Serial.println(" *C");
  }
}
```

It fails when working with ESP8266 but when I test it with my Arduino MEGA2560, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Although it depends on the exact model, the output power pins on most ESP8266s are 3.3V.
Most sensors (including the DHT11) prefer an input closer to 5V. (It claims it can take 3.5V - 5.5V)

This has clowned me in the past and I have a sneaking suspicion that this is what you're running into.

Comment: Can confirm. Works for me. Sorry for necroposting

Comment: I had a similar problem with really wrong humidity and temp measurements (100 and 150 respectively in my case) and discovered that the inexpensive ESP8266 I was using seemed to be delivering insufficient voltage from its 3v supply pin. When I took an Arduino Uno and powered the DHT22 from the 5V supply pin on the Arduino (which was powered by a second USB port), my data improved to realistic values. I've seen other people report similar issues with low cost ESP8266 parts.

Answer (score 1):

Which ESP8266 is it? Is it some development board or ESP-01 or similar? Please give some more information, there are so many of those ESP8266-boards...

Since there is no picture about wiring, one cannot say for sure, but is the pin number correct? I had similar issues with my arduino Uno clone, but the reason then was bad connection/wiring.

RandomNerd has quite good examples: [ESP8266 DHT11/DHT22 Temperature and Humidity Web Server with Arduino IDE](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-dht11dht22-temperature-and-humidity-web-server-with-arduino-ide/)